# OnSensorChanged Thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, service, android-sensors

I need to do a lot of work in method onSensorChanged so my App is freezing.
I tryied to create thread in method OnSensorChanged. It helps a little but creating new thread manytimes per secound is not the best way I think. What should I do?

I created my own sensorService which extends Service and implements SensorEventListener.

```
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    Thread w = new Thread(new Worker(event));
    w.start();

}

class Worker implements Runnable{
    SensorEvent event;
    Worker(SensorEvent event){
        this.event=event;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if(event.sensor.getType()==Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER){
            accelerometerData(event);
        }
        if(event.sensor.getType()==Sensor.TYPE_GRAVITY){
            gravityData(event);
        }
        if(event.sensor.getType()==Sensor.TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION){
            linearAccelerometerData(event);
        }
    }
    private void linearAccelerometerData(SensorEvent event) {
        expensiveWork();
        Intent intent = new Intent("SensorService");
        intent.putExtra("data",data)            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(SensorService.this).sendBroadcast(intent);
    }

    private void accelerometerData(SensorEvent event){  
        expensiveWork2();
        Intent intent = new Intent("SensorService");
        intent.putExtra("data",data)    
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(SensorService.this).sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
}
```

Can I start service on its own thread? Or create just one thread and give him the work?

Comment: How your event should be handled i.e. in FIFO order or any order is fine?

Comment: A service as its own thread so no issue from this point of view and concerning the thread how about a fifo wrote with UI thread and you're worker would read it

Comment: @sakura it must be FIFO

Comment: Are you able to drop arriving updates if processing of current update is not finished yet, or you need to process every sensor update?

Comment: @Salauyou every sensor update.

Comment: @SpeedEX505 so you understand that if you receive for example 10 updates a sec, and every update is processing 0,5 sec, your app will have to work 5 minutes to proceed data that were obtained during 1 minute?

Comment: @SpeedEX505 BTW, I think that separate infinite thread or threads with their own loopers and handlers is what you need. Just send your long tasks as runnables to their handlers--all other work of managing queues and executing those runnables is implemented implicitly.  This should work effectively in case of multi-core processor

Answer (score 2):

You should register listener with a Handler

```
public boolean registerListener (SensorEventListener listener, Sensor sensor, int rateUs, Handler handler)
```

For example

```
// Class members
private HandlerThread mSensorThread;
private Handler mHandler;
```

In `onCreate`

```
mSensorThread = new HandlerThread("sensor_thread"); //$NON-NLS-1$
mSensorThread.start();
mHandler = new Handler(mSensorThread.getLooper());
....
Sensor sensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
if (sensor != null)
{
    mSensorManager.registerListener(this, sensor, your_desired_rate, mHandler);     
}
```

Comment: Which thread is doing onSensorChanged? I thought onSensorChanged() is called by thread of listerner and listener is "this" (service)

Comment: Even though you cannot update the UI from the service, it still runs on the main thread. Read the second paragraph at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html

Answer (score 1):

It seems your thread is just handling event of some type and doing some `expensiveWork()` in threads. As its an event and I think it should be handled in FIFO (First in First out) manner.

So, if its handled in FIFO order, you can go for as a Queue of events and the thread's `run()` method will keep on picking the events from queue. If there is no event, your thread will just keep on waiting for your main thread to keep an new Event and signal it.

Its kind of ideal Producer-Consumer problem where your main thread will keep on adding Events to the queue and your worker thread will keep on consuming those Events one by one. You should think of the optimal queue size etc.

If FIFO order doesn't matter, you can go for ThreadPool to spawn multiple thread which will keep on receiving Events and executing in parallel.

Comment: But how to do blocking of worker thread? I possix where is semaphore. How to do it in java?

Comment: you can find thousands of link showing example of a typical Producer-Consumer problem and its solution. try to google it and come up here again if you couldn't figure out something.